# Fabric Js with full features enabled

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How to get fabric js file with all the features enabled?

In my fabric project, I am using the features: touch events, groups, mouse wheel event etc.

The main js file does not contain the source code for touch events. So I tried downloading the custom build with all features selected from here - http://fabricjs.com/build/. But now the functions in group feature is not working - `"TypeError: canvas.setActiveGroup is not a function"`:

```
var objs = canvas.getObjects();

//create group
var group = new fabric.Group(objs);

group.center().setCoords();

canvas.setActiveGroup(group).renderAll();
```

I have also tried the version available in git - https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

I tried different fabric js files but I didn't get a js file with all the features enabled.

Can anyone help me out to find the fabric js complete version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[v2-breaking-changes](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes-2)

As it is mentioned, `setActiveGroup()` method is removed . If you want to get active selection you can use

`canvas.getActiveObject()` which returns a reference to the current active object.

`canvas.getActiveObjects()` which returns an array containing a reference to the current selected objects, one or many.

Use `canvas.setActiveObject()` to set an object or if you want activeselection you can use `fabric.ActiveSelection`

Here is
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/e4r8v21m/)